# form widgets values

Tags: forms, doctrine, widget, symfony-1.4

I have used form widgets for my user registration which has sales or customer radio buttons
If customer button is checked means i have to insert into registration table and one more table also. So i want to use the form submitted values before executing $form->save();.
How to do this.Pl help me......

My radio button field name is executive_check

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
   $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()),$request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
//i have to check the form user type radio button value here
        $form->save();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
```

Please help me........

Comment: I'd also recommend you do your additional saving *after* the registration has been saved, otherwise if this fails you may end up with corrupt/useless data (think redundant "other table" entries if the initial save doesn't happen correctly)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should override save method on your form, and do not change anything on your actions.

For example:

```
class BookForm extends BaseBookForm {
    public function save($con = null) {
        if($this->getValue('isCustomer')) {
            // do your additional save  
        }
        return parent::save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access posted variable from the form you have to overwrite the save() function in your registration form and you can access all of the post variables in one array with name "$this->values". Please try like below

```
public function save($con = null){

 // This will list out whole array of the posted variables.
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($this->values);

// to use your field variable with named "executive_check" you can get value by below syntax

if($this->values['executive_check'] == 'radiobuttonValue'){
  // your logic if sales or customer radio button is selected.
 }
  // will call parent form save function to save all data
 parent::save($con);
}
```

Comment: Documentation recommends overriding `doSave()` rather than `save().`

Comment: I agree with you richsage, even it is possible to use it in save() function.